# How is next defined in a custom react redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux

[Going through the process of middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), Dan defines `next` to the the original dispatch, but in creating the middleware, he doesn't. Where and how is `next` defined here:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd(action.type)
  return result
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how the logger has next passed into it?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i'm asking

Comment: is store and next something that is passed in by #applyMiddleware? why is it called next if it's referring to the dispatch from the previous middleware?

Comment: the middleware stops the next action from automatically being fired so you can execute whatever inside, for example you can log the action. So it gives you a little break in between to do whatever you want. It's called next because it is the "next" action being dispatched, it is what continues the current dispatch. Think of it like "I am done doing what I need to do in this middleware so lets move onto the **next** thing".

Comment: but in the docs, dan uses next to refer to the original dispatch

Comment: It's whatever dispatch that is passed to it

Comment: It is named `next` in that it is a convention to name it so in a middleware. Same thing In Express and Koa. Quite a good name IMHO. It's also great that Redux took it as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Where**

`next` is supplied by [`applyMiddleware`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js#L30).

**How**

From the referenced source,

```
var middlewareAPI = {
  getState: store.getState,
  dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action)
}
chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)
```

`middlewareAPI` is the first level argument passed to a middleware.
It is named `store` conventionally.

`store.dispatch` is the supplied `next`, which is the second level argument.